# Cypress clicking on a button with href"..." does not return information that it should

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I am working with react app and have a href button that supposed to take me the new url but also load some information for a dropdown on the next page. below is the button code

```
 <a class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text jss1069 depth-2 jss1073" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" href="...." aria-current="page">
    <span class="MuiButton-label">Programs</span>
   <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root">
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-ripple MuiTouchRipple-rippleVisible" style="width: 276.159px; height: 276.159px; top: -126.08px; left: -69.0797px;"></span></span></a>
```

My cypress code i tried to click on it.

```
cy.get('button[style="padding-left: 40px;"]',{timeout: 10000})
            .should('be.visible')
            .click()
              
cy.get('a[href="......"]')
.should('be.visible')
.click()
```

i tried getting it with href ,with contains, timing out visible and etc. it does click on it but then API call behind it does not load info i need and show errors on Cypress runner even tho it returned 200.
This is runner screen in yellow shows that weird error and consol says "you need a javascript to run this app". I have js enabled aswell on browser.
[Runner screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW4vb.png)

I added exception handling and it worked few runs and then started doing the same thing

```
cy.get('a[href="/setup/academics/programs"]')
        .should('be.visible')
        .click()
        Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
        return false
         })
```

Any input is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I could see that your application is generating exceptions. To handle exceptions you can add this after the click.

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})
```

Comment: Holly motherload of Cypress.it worked. i did use that exception handling but later in the code so i guess it did not apply to that click. I do Appreciate your help

Comment: Well it was short lived. it worked only few runs and now does the same thing( even with that code